# Is there a way to use Instagram API/Facebook Login without Business Verification?

Tags: facebook, instagram

I have been messing around with Instagram Graph API and Basic Display.I am making a desktop app and  want a user to be able to log in so that I can use their information to display their Instagram information. This is not for consumer use, but really just as a project to learn for myself. Problem is, it appears Graph API, Basic Display, and Facebook Login all require Business verification.

I do not have a business, nor any intention of using this for a business. I still tried to find a way around this, but nothing has worked. I found some slightly older information online which says it's not possible to do this without Business verification. I want to know if anyone has any updated information on this, or if it is still the same. I don't really understand why Basic Display requires business verification for authorization if the application will never be used in any real sense. Still hoping there's a way around this, any information would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't plan to ever make the app "live", then you don't need to submit for review or business verification. It will only be usable by people you added to a role in your app then though. (If you need to add more people besides your already existing admin account, those need to be registered as Facebook developers though, otherwise you won't be able to add them.) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles And if you were to publish any content via that app, it would only be visible to people with a role in the app as well.

Comment: I see. I was hoping to practice any user logging in, even if they don't have a role, but I see it's not possible without verification. Thank you.